# Menu order of parent menu from perspective of child menu

Tags: theme-development, sub-menu, child-pages, menu-order

I have developed a theme which has a **parent menu** and a **sub-menu**. It looks something like:

```
Main menu              ==> category | price | depot

sub menu for category  ==> tag| name | date (show/hide)
sub menu for price     ==> currency | date (show/hide)
etc...
```

I am using a **redirect template** that redirects automatically to first tab of child menu when i click on parent menu. Ie if I open :

```
http://host/category
```

it will redirect to:

```
http://host/category/tag
```

## Question

I would like to get the **parent's menu_order** from child menu. ie , when loaded:

```
http://host/category/tag
```

I want to get the order (0,1,2...) of the parent ie **"category"** tab.
How is this done in WP?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using **'menu_order':**

```
function parent_menu_order($post) {
   if( isset($post->post_parent) ) {
      if($post->post_parent == 0) {
         return $post->menu_order;
      }// if no parent,  return it itself
      $post_data = get_post($post->post_parent);
      return $post_data->menu_order;
   } else {
      return -1;
   }
}
```